# "Open recent" dropdown disapeared from New Tab in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Looks like Google Chrome updated itself again and the appearance of the New tab changed. Unfortunately this page missed "Open recent" feature which I used often :(

How can I configure it back?

Answer (score 2):

Of course ctrl+shft+T will open the last closed tab,  if that is not sufficient there is still the open recently closed tab in the settings dialogue. No need to open a new tab,  just go there and select the site you want to reopen and a new tab will open.

PS didn't find  a way to configure it back though

[image]

Edit:well if you closed the whole browser it allows you to open all tabs at once, but other than that I think the session buddy might be the way to go :)

Comment: In this case I could open the tabs only one by one. Which can be a real headache if there was many of them in the last session :( Thank you for the contribution!

Answer (score 0):

You could try a Session Buddy extension, it's very useful.

[Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en)

By the  way you could use **Ctrl-Shift-T** to get your recently closed tabs.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-T opens only ONE last tab. The naive "open recent" dropdown provided me with a feature to open several tabs from the last session in one click. Thank you for the link to a extension. I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

1. **Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.**
2. Select `Recent Tabs.`
3. Select the desired tab from the list under `"Recently closed".`
4. Repeat these steps to retrieve more recently closed tabs.

I am guessing that is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all type in the omnibar: chrome://flags/

Then find the option Enable Instant Extended API and set it to disabled

Reboot chrome
You should have the recent tabs bar back

I hope this solved your problem